# Iframe height doesn't fill out to 50%

Tags: html, css, wordpress, iframe

I'm currently working on my exam project and am building a wordpress theme (which I have converted to HTML for CodePen).

It's working but sadly all my iframes i'm using for my podcasts get stuck at a set height instead of filling out like I wanted to. I tried a lot to fix this, but can't get it to work.

the codepen is available at 
https://codepen.io/Puffss/pen/weWPmW

And is mainly about the

```css
iframe {
  background: url(img/placeholdersoundcloud.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 18%;
  height: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0% 1% 0.6% 1%;
}
```

```html
<iframe width="640" height="400" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="./SpaarnestadPhoto Exposities_files/saved_resource.html"></iframe>
```

Please note: this is the code wordpress generated as a single webpage, hence the weird code and missing links in the iframe.

Comment: Remove height and width from the inline iframe, give it a class and use css to adjust it

Comment: I tried this, but sadly Wordpress automatically includes the inline height and width, and i can't ask my client to remove them by hand every time they release a new podcast

Comment: @DaisyTammer use jquery to set the height of iframe after page load $("iframe").height("50%");

Comment: I tired doing that, but sadly didn't give any result

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css

```
iframe{
  height:50% !important;
  width: 600px;
}
```

It will override the inline height with the one you want (in this case, 50%) for all the tag `<iframe>`

I also suggest you to check why WordPress automatically sets the height and width, and maybe try to get rid of them from the source as usually using important it's not the best practice https://codepen.io/NickHG/pen/BZzJKZ

Comment: I tried doing this in the theme, and sadly it doesn't give a result at all. instead it returns to default height